# jQuery document ready fadeIn doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm trying to make a site where when you enter, everything fades in.
Here is my code:

```js
var celyLogin = $(".container");

$(document).ready(function () {
    /*! Fades in page on load */
    $("container").css("display", "none");
    $("container").fadeIn(5000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="container">
    <div>
        <h1>WELCOME USER</h1>

        <div id="UandP">
            <h3>
                Username: <input class="username" type="text" name="username">
            </h3>

            <h3>
                Password: <input class="password" type="password" name="password">
            </h3>
        </div>

        <input type="button" class="submit" value="Log In" name="submit" onclick="validate()">
    </div>
</div>
```

It's probably a small problem but I can't find it..

Comment: `$("container")` is `<container>` Your element has an id, so you need an id selector

Comment: class selector `.` is missing from `$("container").css('display', 'none');`

Comment: @brk that still will not work... it ain't a class

Comment: Still doesn't work. I even tried to switch everything to class

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the hashtage:

```js
$("#container").css('display', 'none');
$("#container").fadeIn(5000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="container">
  <h1>WELCOME USER</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out in comments, your selectors are wrong. Container is an id and should be:

```js
var celyLogin = $("#container");

$(document).ready(function(){

    /*! Fades in page on load */
    $("#container").css("display", "none");
    $("#container").fadeIn(5000);

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `$("container")` with `$("#container")`. You can refer to ID-s with the # symbol, like CSS.